# Решение не создается в Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022

Выбираю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее настройки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После кнопки создать VS перестаёт работать, проект не создается(точнее .sln создается забаганным)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

VS восстанавливал, обновлял, переустанавливал

Старые проекты открываются проблемы именно с созданием новых

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: .NET 6 попробуйте вместо Core, может с шаблонами что-то не то. А вообще sln - это текстовый файл.

Comment: @aepot не помогло, да и проект должен быть на 3.1

Comment: 3.1 устарел и разницы между ними немного. А так, ошибку такую никогда не видел. Ради прикола попробуйте от имени администратора студию стартануть.

Comment: @aepot ожидаемо не помогло, щас проверил, но не работают даже просто консольные приложения и т. д. просто пустые решения создаются (хотя папка проекта создается нормально)

Comment: Откуда студию брали? Дистрибутив.

Comment: VS INSTALLER щас попробую 2019 скачать

Comment: Откуда, я имею в виду источник

Comment: @aepot с офф сайта, конечно же

Comment: Тогда магия какая-то. Попробуйте другую папку для создания решения, я хз) Русские буквы в пути к папке есть?

Comment: @aepot уже попробовал, путь из анл символов, всёравно не работает

Comment: Винда какая? У меня на 10 и 11 работает, не кашляет. Антивирус кастомный есть? Если да, отключите временно или добавьте папку с решениями в исключения.

Comment: [Repair](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2022)

Answer (score 0):

Ну вообщем поставил 2019 версию всё работает